# How to get size of nested std::initializer_lists?

Tags: c++, c++11

`std::initializer_list` has a member function [size](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/size) that returns the number of elements in the initializer list.

Considering there is no `[]` operator for a `std::initializer_list`, and a user does not want to use `for-loop` to access the size of each sub-list:

How can a user get the size of an inner `std::initializer_list` from `std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list>`.

For example, from the following example, could you please tell me how a user can access the size of the first nested initializer_list, `{1, 2, 3}`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::initializer_list<std::initializer_list<int>> a = { {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4} };

  std::cout << a.size() << std::endl; // Provides = 2

  // Now I want to access the size of the first nested std::initializer_list:
  // std::cout << a[0].size() << std::endl; // Does not compile

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot use the subscript operator, there is none for the initialiser list see [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of [`std::initializer_list::begin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list/begin),

> Returns a pointer to the first element in the initializer list.

e.g.

```
std::cout << a.begin()->size() << std::endl;       // Provides = 3
std::cout << (a.begin() + 1)->size() << std::endl; // Provides = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
for(const auto& ilist: a)
   std::cout << ilist.size() << std::endl; // Compiles
```

See **[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YfEP4r4Kd1fgZU70)**.

If required, you can assign the sizes to different variables within the `for` loop.

Comment: I did not want to use for-loop as mentioned in the question, yet many thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed that part. If you don't mind, I will let this answer remain so that it might be useful for others who can use the `for` loop.

Comment: Please do so. I also upvoted for my appreciation. Many thanks for your time.